# Getting error when installing FileZilla on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, filezilla

Currently, I am working on `Ubuntu 13.10 with 64 bit` OS.
I have tried Ubuntu software center to install FileZilla but, It does not installing showing me error either for connenction or other issue.

I have tries with Terminal also.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

But, It shows me

```
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,184 kB/8,583 kB of archives.
After this operation, 25.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libtinyxml2.6.2 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 filezilla-common filezilla
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe libwxbase2.8-0 amd64 2.8.12.1-14ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/universe libwxgtk2.8-0 amd64 2.8.12.1-14ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe filezilla amd64 3.7.3-1ubuntu1 [1,299 kB]
Fetched 197 kB in 4s (44.8 kB/s)       
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1-14ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1-14ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How to get install FileZilla? Please give some way..

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.10 isn't supported anymore.

You have to [install a newer version](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) of Ubuntu (and this is my suggestion) or [enable EOL repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).

Anyway, questions about Ubuntu should be asked on askubuntu.com